# New attribute not save in table Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup

Tags: attributes, configuration, sql, database-update

My script runs perfect but dont save the new attribute in database.... why? thanks.
`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Itep_Incomm>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Itep_Incomm>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <incomm>
                <class>Itep_Incomm_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>incomm_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </incomm>
        </models>

        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <incomm_virtual translate="label" module="incomm">
                        <label>Incomm Virtual</label>
                        <model>incomm/product_virtual</model>
                        <price_model>incomm/product_price</price_model>
                        <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    </incomm_virtual>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>

        <resources>
            <incomm_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Itep_Incomm</module>
                    <class>Itep_Incomm_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_setup>
            <incomm_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_write>
            <incomm_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_read>
        </resources>

    </global>
</config>
```

Script install in folder `sql/incomm_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();


    //incomm_request_active_code att order
    $installer->addAttribute('order_item','incomm_request_active_code', 
        array(
            'type' => 'text', 
            'grid' => false 
        )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

And the `model/resource/eav/mysql4/setup.php`

```
    <?php
    class Itep_Incomm_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
    {

}
```

When i run the script, and go to search in database, i cant find the new attribute in table `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`, but the script shows in `core_resouce`, why my code is not saving? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i only deleted the setupDBinstallSQL custom in `core_resource` and solved when running again the installer

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that did not run due to the version number being the same, to be sure check your DB with this query:

```
select * from core_resource where code like '%Itep_Incomm%';
```

Check what is the current version for your module. If it's already 0.1.0 then try to rename your install script to mysql4-install-0.1.0-0.2.0.php
and then update your config.xml to 0.2.0, finally flush your cache and run again. Also make sure that update scripts run automatically in your configuration, or you can manually run the updater from the console like this:

```
php shell/Updater.php
```

Doing this you will be able to see the errors in the console.

For more information check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766837/1016425

Comment: in `core_resources` doesnt show the version of module... module version is 0.1.0, same of this installer , i checked the link but my script runs, and column incomm_setup is inserted in core_resource, only the new attribute dont save in  table `sales_flat_order_item`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

Note that is using `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`
Put this in your config.xml setup declaration:

```
     <resources>
        <module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Vendor_Module</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </module_setup>
    </resources>
```